# How to append and subtract values from a global or local var permanently and update its values without oop

Tags: python, if-statement, logic-error

I am trying to create a simple atm ui from if-else without using oop, I'm having a hard time figuring out how can I permanently add and subtract a value from my variable "bal" and show updated results, when I run it it does add and subtract when I "Withdraw" and "Deposit" but when i choose "Balance" it still gives me the initial value.

```
bal = 737000
if pin == pwd:
    print("""
                1) Balance
                2) Withdraw
                3) Deposit
                4) Cancel Transaction       
        
        
        
        
        """)
    try:
        opt = int(input("Please choose your transaction "))
    except:
        print("Invalid input, input must be an integer.")

    if opt == 1:
        print(f"Your current balance is ₱{bal}.00")

    if opt == 2:
        withdraw = int(input("Please enter amount: "))
        balance = bal - withdraw
        print(f"₱{bal}.00 is withdrawn from your account...")
        print(f"Your updated balance is ₱{balance}.00")

    if opt == 3:
        deposit = int(input("How much money would you like to deposit?: "))
        balance = bal + deposit
        print(f"₱{deposit}.00 is deposited unto your account...")
        print(f"Your updated balance is ₱{balance}.00")

    if opt == 4:
        break
else:
    print("Please enter a valid pin and try again.")
```

Is a workaround still possible, I need to add and subtract values from my "bal" variable permanently and show updated results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a second, redundant variable (`balance`) and don't update your main variable (`bal`) after deposit/withdraw operations. Try this:

```
   ...
   if opt == 2:
      withdraw = int(input("Please enter amount: "))
      bal = bal - withdraw
      print(f"₱{withdraw}.00 is withdrawn from your account...")
      print(f"Your updated balance is ₱{bal}.00")
   if opt == 3:
      deposit = int(input("How much money would you like to deposit?: "))
      bal = bal + deposit
      print(f"₱{deposit}.00 is deposited unto your account...")
      print(f"Your updated balance is ₱{bal}.00")
   ...
```

Answer (score -2):

your variable is global if you re run the code than it will reassign the value of bal

```py
bal = 737000
if pin == pwd:
```

it is reassigning the variable that is why you variable still giving you previous value

Comment: Yes, the intent is to assign `bal`, but the OP knows this already. This is not the reason that the expected result is not displaying.